# How to access the event arguments passed to a ColdBox module?

Tags: module, coldfusion, coldbox

I have a view in my ColdBox application that is calling a module handler within the view like this:

`#runEvent( event="mymodule:home.index" )#`

Now I want to pass arguments to the module, so I changed the call to this:

`#runEvent( event="mymodule:home.index", eventArguments=moduleArgs )#`

Though unfortunately I don't seem to have access to the passed arguments within the module's event handler. I've dumped `rc` and `prc`, but they only contain variables I've set in the main event handler and the `event` argument doesn't seem to provide a method to return the passed arguments. The [documentation about module event executions](https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/content/full/modules/module_event_executions.html) unfortunately doesn't provide any information about this.

Also, I realized calling `event.getCurrentModule()` within the module returns an empty string. I would have expected the module's name.

So, how can I access the arguments passed to a module? Is `runEvent()` the right function for this? Did I miss a module config setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define arguments in your function like this

```
function index(event, rc, prc, isRender=false) {
  writedump(arguments);
  abort;
}
```

See the [ColdBox `runEvent()` documentation](https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/content/full/event_handlers/executing_events.html).

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I totally missed that point in the documentation.

Comment: The documentation link has been moved here: https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/the-basics/event-handlers/executing-events

Answer (score 1):

The [ColdBox documentation](https://coldbox.ortusbooks.com/content/full/event_handlers/executing_events.html) explains how to pass additional arguments to your function. So e.g. calling

```
#runEvent( event="mymodule:home.index", eventArguments={foo="bar"} )#
```

the `foo` variable can be accessed via the `arguments` scope:

```
function index(event, rc, prc) {
  writedump(arguments.foo); // Dumps "bar"
}
```